# FFMPEG Multiple task for converting video to image sequence for MacOS

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, images

I need help to make multiple task of that on MacOS:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -r 0.1 output_%04d.jpg
```

I have basically 200 video files to do that action and I want to create a single code that I can send to ffmpeg at once. I have tried with & in the end but it didn't work.

please help!
Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process multiple videos in a single command:

```
ffmpeg -i video0.mp4 -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -map 0:v -r 0.1 video0_%04d.jpg -map 1:v -r 0.1 video1_%04d.jpg -map 2:v -r 0.1 video2_%04d.jpg -map 3:v -r 0.1 video3_%04d.jpg
```

I am not sure how many you can do at once.

Comment: Thank you llogan for your answer and help. However what I am looking for is to do multiple tasks of: ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -r 0.1 output_%04d.jpg
For example, I have the video1.mp4 , video2.mp4 , video3.mp4, video4.mp4 etc, and I wanna extract images every 10 seconds from them but not one by one, but all at the same time. So find a code that group that task with multiple files simultaneously.

Comment: it didn't work llogan :( it created the image sequences with the names video0_%04d.jpg, video1_%04d.jpg, video2_%04d.jpg..... but all of them were made from them same video mp4 file. So I had many copies of the same image sequences with different names

Comment: Now its showing that message: 
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:1. Default encoder for format image2 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:1

Comment: @GabrielMoraesAquino See updated answer. This time I actually tested and confirmed it worked instead of being lazy. By the number of ffmpeg answers I've given you'd think I'd know how to use it.

Comment: yesss it works!!! so good the feeling of seeing the numbers scrolling down automatically <3